# Java 8 date/time: instant, could not be parsed at index 19

Tags: java, date, parsing, time, java.time.instant

I have following piece of code:

```
String dateInString = "2016-09-18T12:17:21:000Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateInString);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

It gives me following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text '2016-09-18T12:17:21:000Z' could not be parsed at index 19   at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
>     at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>     at java.time.Instant.parse(Instant.java:395)    at
>   core.domain.converters.TestDateTime.main(TestDateTime.java:10)

When I change that last colon to a full stop:

```
String dateInString = "2016-09-18T12:17:21.000Z";
```

…then execution goes fine:

> 2016-09-18T15:17:21+03:00[Europe/Kiev]

So, the question is - how to parse date with `Instant` and `DateTimeFormatter`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "problem" is the colon before milliseconds, which is non-standard (standard is a decimal point).

To make it work, you must build a custom `DateTimeFormatter` for your custom format:

```
String dateInString = "2016-09-18T12:17:21:000Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, false)
    .appendLiteral('Z')
    .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime instant = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, formatter);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

Output of this code:

```
2016-09-18T12:17:21+03:00[Europe/Kiev]
```

---

If your datetime literal had a dot instead of the last colon, things would be much simpler.

Comment: Actually the standard is a COMMA *or* a FULL STOP (period), with the **comma being preferred**. See *ISO 8601:2004* Third edition 2004-12-01, section “4.2.2.4 Representations with decimal fraction”: … the decimal fraction shall be divided from the integer part by the decimal sign specified in ISO 31-0, i.e. the comma [,] or full stop [.]. Of these, the comma is the preferred sign. …

Comment: @basil Maybe for ISO, but not in the JDK, [which uses the decimal point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFraction-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-boolean-)

Comment: any idea about my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57174218/whats-the-easiest-way-to-parse-a-dateformat-in-java-such-that-the-resulting-dat?noredirect=1#comment100861120_57174218

Answer (score 3):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String dateInString = "2016-09-18T12:17:21:000Z";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS");
Instant instant = sdf.parse(dateInString).toInstant();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

> 2016-09-18T19:17:21+03:00[Europe/Kiev]

Answer (score -3):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy");

String date = "16/08/2016";

//convert String to LocalDate
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

If the `String` is formatted like `ISO_LOCAL_DATE`, you can parse the String directly, no need conversion.

```
package com.mkyong.java8.date;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class TestNewDate1 {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        String date = "2016-08-16";

        //default, ISO_LOCAL_DATE
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);

        System.out.println(localDate);

    }

}
```

Check out this site 
[Site here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)

Comment: What about the time component?