# How to parse a UTC offset dateformat string into the resulting date separated by | symbol

Tags: java, android, datetime-format, java-time, date

I have a very peculiar question where I am trying to parse `"2019-12-25T17:00:00-05:00"`
such that it should give me the result `DEC 12 | Thursday | 5:00pm`

I tried the following code by using `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate`

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz", Locale.US);
                DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM d | E | hh:mm a", Locale.US);
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2019-12-25T17:00:00-05:00", inputFormatter);
                String formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(date);
                contentTextView.setText(formattedDate);
```

but it crashes with `DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-12-25T17:00:00-05:00' could not be parsed at index 19`

Any idea why it's crashing and if my output will render the expected result?
Thanks!

Comment: try with this one "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'"
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", Locale.US)

Comment: with that change , I get this crash : DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-12-25T17:00:00-05:00' could not be parsed at index 16

Comment: how about this "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSXXX" or "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"

Comment: same issue with that one : DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-12-25T17:00:00-05:00' could not be parsed at index 19

Comment: I'm wondering close votes on this question, is this really unclear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your String `2019-12-25T17:00:00-05:00` represents `UTC` timezone with offset [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), so use `OffsetDateTime` for parsing that string

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-12-25T17:00:00-05:00");

System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d | E | hh:mm a", Locale.US)));
```

If you want to set particular time zone you can use `atZoneSameInstant` to pass `ZoneId` for eaxmple

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(zone);
```

Comment: this seems to work, however ,I get the result : 112 25 | Wed | 05:00 PM, instead of the Month Dec , is MM the right format for this?

Comment: awesome, just one last issue, is there a way to convert AM | PM To lowercase am | pm, without using replace?

Comment: i do see only upper case here `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html, is that a problem? @AngelaHeely

Comment: not a big issue, just curious, as the ideal format I was looking for was "DEC 12|Wed| 5:00 pm" where am /pm is in lowercase and month is in uppercase. if its not straightforward, no big deal

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way until you replace in output string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581608/displaying-am-and-pm-in-lower-case-after-date-formatting @AngelaHeely

Comment: Good link, @Deadpool. In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42466448/5772882).

Comment: any idea about this one? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57695243/how-do-i-set-timezone-on-a-specific-date?noredirect=1#comment101834800_57695243

Answer (score 3):

### A way to format uppercase DEC and lowercase pm

I’m just giving a small supplement to @Deadpool’s good answer. A way of getting the month abbreviation in all caps like `DEC` and am/pm in lowercase is a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its two-arg `appendText​(TemporalField, Map<Long,String>)` method.

```
    Locale userLocale = Locale.US;
    Map<Long, String> monthNames = new HashMap<>();
    for (Month m : Month.values()) {
        monthNames.put(Long.valueOf(m.getValue()),
                m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, userLocale).toUpperCase(userLocale));
    }
    Map<Long, String> amPmNames = new HashMap<>(3);
    amPmNames.put(0L, "am");
    amPmNames.put(1L, "pm");
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, monthNames)
            .appendPattern(" d | E | hh:mm ")
            .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, amPmNames)
            .toFormatter(userLocale);

    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-12-25T17:00:00-05:00");
    String formattedDate = odt.format(outputFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output:

> DEC 25 | Wed | 05:00 pm

I have assumed that you are programming for Android under API level 26 and using ThreeTenABP, so I have tested on my desktop Java 7 with ThreeTen Backport. From Java 8 and on newer API levels and even more from Java 9 more elegant ways to populate the two maps exist.

### What went wrong in your code?

The lowercase `z` that comes last in your format pattern string matches a *time zone name*. The documentation gives examples Pacific Standard Time and PST. It doesn’t match an offset like `-05:00`. If you ever need a format pattern letter for this, use `x`, `X` or uppercase `Z` (they are different and all well documented). However, as already shown in Deadpool’s answer, you need no explicit formatter and no format pattern string in this case.

Another issue in your code: The `LocalDate` class that you used in the question is a date without time of day. You can parse your string into a `LocalDate`, but the time of day and offset get lost. Hence you cannot format the `LocalDate` into a string that contains time of day. For that you need a class that has `DateTime` in its name, for example `OffsetDateTime` used in the two answers.

### Link

[`DateTimeFormatter` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) spelling out all the possible format pattern letters.