# How do I set timezone on a specific date?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have an issue where I tried all ways(including online stackoverflow threads), but am not able to set timezone as expected on a specific date.
Here's my code:

```
Date until = DateTimeUtils.getNewBookUntilDate();
//which returns : Wed Aug 28 11:00:02 EDT 2019 

SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
            isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
try {
    until = isoFormat.parse(until.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I still get : Wed Aug 28 11:00:02 EDT 2019 , instead of Wed Aug 28 8:00:02 PDT 2019

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: a Date doesn't have a timezone. Only when you create a string to represent it is the timezone taken into consideration. Look into where you are printing your date.

Comment: is there no other way I can retrieve the date that  i have based on a current timezone and send it over?

Comment: Give try : set timezone in calendar then use. see this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/TimeZonegetTimeZoneAmericaNewYork.htm)

Comment: that doesnt seem to work either :(

Comment: It might help if you showed the code where you're converting to string / printing.

Comment: *send it over* — where to are you sending it and by what means? I’m sure there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

A `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC. No need to manipulate it as text. Beware: the method **`Date::toString` tells a lie**, dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text.

## Instead, use `java.time.Instant`

First convert from that terrible legacy class to its modern replacement, `java.time.Instant`. Notice the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myDate.toInstant() ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

An `Instant` is also a moment in UTC. To see that same moment through the offset-from-UTC used by the people of a certain region, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Be clear: This `zdt` object and this `instant` object **both represent the same moment**, the same point on the timeline. They are different only in the wall-clock time. Imagine someone in [Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland) (always in UTC) calling someone in Québec, and they both look up at the clock on their respective walls.

## Converting from modern to legacy

If you have a `ZonedDateTime` object in hand, and you must get a `java.util.Date` for interoperating with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert. Go from an `Instant` to a `Date`, by extracting a `Instant` from your `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from ( instant ) ;
```

If you need a `Calendar` rather than `Date`, the conversion is more direct.

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: thanks! how do i convert zonedatetime to date ?

Comment: @AngelaHeely I added a section at the end about converting from modern `ZonedDateTime` & `Instant` classes to the legacy class `java.util.Date`.

Comment: thanks Basil! you are the best! will check it out

Comment: why would you call that a lie? it's simply trying to represent that date in something that makes sense for the reader

Comment: @njzk2 The `Date` value is a moment in UTC. When you report that as being in a particular time zone, you create the illusion that there is a zone stored within the `Date`, when in fact there is not†. If you are storing a money amount in Canadian CAD yet report the amount adjusted into Japanese Yen without any request to do so, I believe any financial institution would consider that a lie. (†Actually there *is* a time zone buried deep within `Date`, but without getters/setters and not affecting `toString` yet affecting `equals` and such – making even more of a mess of a bloody awful class.)

Comment: Hey Basil, any idea about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186900/how-do-i-get-the-text-after-second-occurrence-of-the-character-of-my-string-us